# Export .rpt to PDF in asp.net with parameters in .rpt

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I need to create a procedure to export .rpt to PDF. I am using parameters in .rpt because I am using SQL stored procedure to create the report.

I am developing in asp.net 2008 with VB.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my question.

This is the code, because if you need it.

Regards.

```
    Dim PathFile As String = "c:\Documents" & "\Reporte.pdf"

    formatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat

    Dim oConexInfo As New CrystalDecisions.Shared.TableLogOnInfo
    oConexInfo.ConnectionInfo.ServerName = "SERVER"
    oConexInfo.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = "DBNAME"
    oConexInfo.ConnectionInfo.UserID = "USERID"
    oConexInfo.ConnectionInfo.Password = "PASSWORD"

    rpt.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Imprime.rpt"))

    rpt.SetParameterValue(0, Val(txt_No_Quotation.Text))   ' I send a parameter value
    rpt.Database.Tables(0).ApplyLogOnInfo(oConexInfo)      ' Here I send the credentials for conection to SQL Server with crystal reports

    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt
    ConfigureCRTSTALREPORT()

    rpt.ExportToDisk(formatType, PathFile)     ' Here I export the pdf to disk (in server side)
```